# Bootstrap 3 Text on the right of thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a question, basically  using the thumbnails is ok, and you can get text beneath the tumbnail but i would like to put like 3 tags next to the thumbnail, something like that and would like to have:

[image]

Or those parameters outside of the border, but the border should be very close to the thumbnail ...

The code is following:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    <img data-src="holder.js/100%x180" src="untitled.png" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
    <ul>
    <li>Title</li>
    <li>Location</li>
    <li>Price</li>
    <ul>
  </a>
</div>
```

From the post and responses i get the following in the fiddle, as well as in my solution, i marked it yellow, as you can see the border is somehow on the top now :( :

[image]

[image]

This is final screen, still broken: :(
[image]

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer 9, same in IE 9, in Chrome i get the title location and price which are located ON the thumbnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's quite easy, just divide the region in 2 equal parts and fill in the contents.

http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/D5M7E/3/

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100%x180" src="untitled.png" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>Title</li>
            <li>Location</li>
            <li>Price</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: strange, but now i get issue with this round border, which is then broken :(

Comment: link too, but when i apply what you gave me i get the round border that is around thumbnail which goes up ....

Comment: strange, it works for me :/

also I forgot to mention about the CSS; I've used Inline-Flex MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes     CSS-TRICKS: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Put that information in your answer, not a comment. Fiddle link is working now.

Comment: I'd do something similar to this, but with an additional `.row` element, per Bootstrap's suggestion: 

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cj7n8 I'm not sure it's valid to have all that inside an anchor, however.

Comment: strange for both answers in fiddle i see that the border is broken at the top :(

Comment: what border are you talking about :s ?

Comment: Hey, sorry I was bit busy. I changed the display type to block and gave a proper width and height to the div and I guess your issue is resolved. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/D5M7E/5/

Comment: yes, almost, except i don't know why but now the text is outside of the border, and not inside :/, when on full screen the text is outside, when on small screen the text is inside

Comment: and by outside i mean under the thumbnail outside of the border

Comment: can you post a screenshot again please?

Comment: That's really strange. Which browser are you using?

Comment: maybe then instead of this approach i should use table ...? and in table one column i put thumbnail and then text in the other one?

Comment: I have no issues with this code on Chrome and IE 10 http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/D5M7E/5/

Comment: nope, not for me, i don't know ... i updated the solution with total screen, in full mode, if i make screen like small for tablet, then yes they become good, but like this it is ... so. But maybe you can advise me an other way to have something like this, maybe with table?

Comment: In that case I suggest you writing your own widths for the classes in pixels for different resolutions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that default bootstrap display property is set to block. Just change it to inline-flex or inline-block and thats it. For example:

```
<div id="someId" class="col-md-6">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100%x180" src="untitled.png" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>Title</li>
            <li>Location</li>
            <li>Price</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Just set id  and in css write

```
#someId .thumbnail{
    display: inline-flex;
}
```